# Sort array usling Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I would like to sort an Array using Swift

```
let array: [Any] = [2, 3, 4, [0, 2], 0]
```

Desired output:

```
[0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: `let array = [2,3,4,[0,2],0]` isn't even valid Swift. You need a type annotation like `: [Any]` to allow it to handle the heterogeneous types.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov Pre Swift 3, Swift would actually infer that to be `[NSObject]` by implicitly bridging to `NSNumber` and `NSArray`  (if Foundation was imported) – although in pure Swift (and post Swift 3), it is indeed ambiguous.

Comment: @Hamish Only if `Foundation` is imported. Did you mean `NSNumber`?

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov Ah yes, yes I did ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
let array: [Any] = [2,3,4,[0,2],0]
let sorted = array.flatMap{ $0 as? [Int] ?? [$0 as! Int]}.sort()
```

Comment: Just for fun, one crazy way you could avoid the force-cast would be to use another `??` and a `map`: `let sorted = array.flatMap{ $0 as? [Int] ?? ($0 as? Int).map{[$0]} ?? []}.sort()`.